# How could I make my own lazy iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, lazy-evaluation

I'm making a C++11 class that produces a huge amount of data. That data currently comes from a database and it cannot fit entirely in memory. I would like to provide the user with an iterator that behaves like regular STL iterators, but that would be lazy. More precisely, I would be able to do something like that :

```
for (auto& item : big_bunch_of_data) {
    do_stuff_with(item);
}
```

With item being retrieved from the database only at each iteration. If I'm right, this new syntax is sugar for

```
for (stuff::iterator it = big_bunch_of_data.begin();it != big_bunch_of_data.end();it++) {
    do_stuff_with(*it);
}
```

Does it mean that by providing `begin`, `end` and `operator++`, I could have the desired behavior ? And, what are these methods supposed to do ? I mean, can I make them lazy without breaking stuff ?

Comment: _"That data currently comes from a database and it cannot fit entirely in memory"_ so, without knowing your database it is difficult to give better advice... but remember that many SQL databases provide their own internal iterator mechanisms in the form of _cursors_ which may be of use to you here.

Comment: I'm using sqlite, but that might change in the future, and I don't want to expose raw pointers to the users of my code, that's why I'm trying to encapsulate its rather good (and yes, already lazy) API.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Almost; the compiler will look in a few other places to get the begin and end iterators if it can't find `begin` or `end` methods on the container class; this is how range-based for loops work on arrays, that don't have `begin` and `end` members.  It will also look for free functions `begin` and `end` by ADL, and eventually `std::begin` and `std::end`, so there's plenty of opportunity to retrofit range-based for loop support to existing containers.  [Section 6.5.4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) covers the details.

For your other question, iterators absolutely can be lazy!  A good example is `std::istream_iterator` which *has* to be lazy as it reads input from the console.

The requirement to use an iterator in a `for` loop is that it should satisfy the *input iterator* category, which is described in [section 24.2.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf); the required operations for that category are `!=`, unary `*`, and pre- and post-increment `++`.

To let the language know that you've created an input iterator, you should inherit from `std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T, void, T *, T &>` where `T` is the type your iterator deals in ([section 24.4.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)).

Comment: Actually, no. It uses `.begin()` member functions directly. And if no such members are found it uses `begin` through ADL, not necessarily `std::begin`.